# Change font type in \newtcbox to \texttt

Tags: typewriter, tcblisting

I wanted to change the font type to `\texttt` inside of the LIB box:

[image]

This code is found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181082/how-to-reproduce-this-box-in-tcolorbox/278063#278063):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mylib}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,rotate=90] {LIB} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}


\begin{document}

\mylib{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the option

```
fontupper=\ttfamily
```

[image: typewriter text]