# tcolorbox : how to make a variant of the mylib

Tags: tcolorbox

This question :

[How to reproduce this box in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181082/how-to-reproduce-this-box-in-tcolorbox#)

has a clear answer. I wanted to make a variant which was similar with two small changes :

-instead of LIB, use REMARKS (ok, that's trivial)

-format the text in bullets (itemize environment)

```
\newtcbox{\myremarks}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,rotate=90] {REMARKS} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}


\NewDocumentCommand\remarks{m} 
{\myremarks{\begin{itemize} #1\end{itemize}}}
```

will fail on this :

```
\remarks
{
\item Perfect relationships of $r=\pm1$ do not exist in the real world.
\item Correlation does not imply causation
}
```

fails noting a missing item, so there is some kind of parsing issue going on.

It is likely that ideal way to do this would be modify the newtcbox directly so that it formats the text in the itemize, but I don't even know where to begin to do that.

Comment: You should not use a tcbox but a tcolorbox for everything spanning more than one line.

Comment: Please always provide complete examples which starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` (also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) instead of code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Option `varwidth upper=\linewidth` is used (with `varwidth` packaged loaded) to allow `\myremarks` to typeset its argument in paragraph mode, which is required by `itemize` environment. This is equivalent to `\myremarks{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth} ...\end{varwidth}}`.
- Since the rotated text `REMARKS` is higher than minimal height of `\myremarks`, option `height from=1.2cm to \maxdimen` is used to set a minimum height.
- Node options `pos=1, anchor=south east` are added to attach text `REMARKS` to the top, rather than vertically centered.
- `enumitem` options `noitemsep, leftmargin=5mm` are for adjusting spaces of `itemize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtcbox{\myremarks}{
  enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,
  boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,
  before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
      \fill[green!75!blue!50!white] 
        (frame.south west) rectangle 
          node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,rotate=90, pos=1, anchor=south east] {REMARKS}
        ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}
  },
  % equivalent to surround the cmd arg in "varwidth" env
  varwidth upper=\linewidth,
  % set minimum height for complete output of rotated "REMARKS"
  height from=1.2cm to \maxdimen,
}

\NewDocumentCommand\remarks{m}{%
  \myremarks{%
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=5mm]
      #1%
    \end{itemize}
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\remarks{
  \item abc
}

\remarks{
  \item abc
  \item def
  \item ghi
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems perfect, and is it possible to center the title? What exactly is the problem with what I wrote, I can't see the difference between it and what you have?

Comment: @CliffStamp 1) Removing `pos=1, anchor=south east` will vertically center the title `REMARKs`. 2) `\myremarks`, like the `\tcbox`, typesets its argument in LR mode (see https://latexref.xyz/Modes.html#Modes) but an `itemize` environment need to be typeset in paragraph mode. In my answer, the upper part is surrounded by a `varwidth` environment, which typesets contents in the required paragraph mode. The [original version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/558916/revisions) of my answer explicitly used `varwidth` env, while the current version uses option `varwidth upper`.

Comment: @CliffStamp Some explanations are added to the answer.