# Vertical alignement of tcolorbox in text

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

I'm trying to align a "mylib" tcolorbox ( as in this post : [How to reproduce this box in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181082/how-to-reproduce-this-box-in-tcolorbox) ) with the text around it (see image below).
However, I can't get the vertical spacing right with the nobeforeafter or a negative 'before skip'

I could use some help on this getting this to work,

Thanks for your help,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\newtcbox{\mylib}[1]{parbox=true,enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=-0.5mm,bottom=0mm,height=2.5mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,
  colframe=black,coltext=black,colback=black!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!75] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny] {#1} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize{ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula \mylib{\fontsize{1.5}{1}{XX}}{YY} augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

I found how to manually set the alignment with baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\newtcbox{\mylib}[1]{parbox=true,enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=-0.5mm,bottom=0mm,height=2.5mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,baseline=0.4mm,
  colframe=black,coltext=black,colback=black!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!75] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny] {#1} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize{ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula \mylib{\fontsize{1.5}{1}{XX}}{YY} augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
}
\end{document}
```

[image]